# Pin tab on Google Chrome (Windows)?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Is there a way to pin a tab on Google Chrome for Windows like you can on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just added this feature to the next version for Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean on the page which opens when you open a new tab ? If so yes, you will need the latest [dev build](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Windows). Next, hover your mouse pointer on the web page thumbnail, you'll see a border, and will be able to pin it using the icon on the upper left corner-

[image: Pin it!]

Comment: No I'm mean on the tab bar up at the top of the screen. You can do this on Ubuntu's version of Google Chrome and I was wondering if it was possible in Windows.

Comment: I haven't used the beta versions on Windows, but it's almost certainly the case that you can. Why not just download and try it?

Answer (score 1):

Some weeks ago there was a choice in context menu called "Pin Tab", but it was scrapped.

Then it began working by *dragging the wanted tab* to just before first tab (to the left end of tab bar), it turned itself to pinned... It used to work also using `--pinned-tab-count=NUMBER` command line argument given to chromium at startup (those were called permanent tabs at that time)

**But currently:** It still does show up momentarily as pinned but pops right back when dragging tab to left end of tab bar (using 38097). So I guess it is not working at the moment... I'm also patiently waiting when it will be fixed :)